# Scaling for games

Tags: modeling, animation, objects, physics, units

I looked and didn't find exactly what i was looking for.

So my question is: does size matter in Blender when making stuff for games (Unity, UE...)?

If some stuff would be scaled wrong in Blender for the game, can i just easily scale it up or down in the game engine without losing nothing?

**Funny exaggerate example:** 
i make and animate a character a size of a building and i just scale it down to the right size in game engine or Blender itself. Could anything be messed up or everything would be fine?

Comment: If it's the case of a character that it might be not good because character might be rigged. And scaling rigged character could be kind of a trouble. In general it is good to model according to some measurements because it'll easier to see scaling of every object regarding to other ones in scene (to match up style / proportions / etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Unity's scaling and won't lose any data in the model but this is not recommended. You should always size objects in Blender [apply scale](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/transform/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html#apply-object-transformations) before going to a game engine. If everything is massive and then scaled down to a small percentage of its original size, physics and lighting may behave weirdly.